# How to set a directive and property binding on an element created with Renderer2

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-renderer2

I want to implement a directive called "upload-file" that would be applied on a `<button>` element. Its usage would be:

```
<button upload-file> Upload a file </button>
```

The directive should add a hidden `<input>` and when the button is clicked the `<input>` element will be clicked by the directive code. The resulting DOM would be:

```
<button upload-file>Upload a file</button>
<input type="file" #uploaderInputEl ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

I try to create the `<input>` element using Renderer2 this way:

```
  private appendInputElement = () => {
    this.inputElement = this._renderer.createElement('input');

    this._renderer.setAttribute(this.inputElement, "type", "file");
    this._renderer.setStyle(this.inputElement, "width", "0");
    this._renderer.setStyle(this.inputElement, "visibility", "hidden");

    this._renderer.setAttribute(this.inputElement, "accept", this.acceptedFileExtensions);
    this._renderer.listen(this.inputElement, "change", (event) => this.inputElement_change(event));

    // set directive: ng2FileSelect
    // set property binding: [uploader]="uploader"

    this._renderer.appendChild(this.containerElement, this.inputElement);
  }
```

But I don't know how to set the `directive` (ng2FileSelect) and `property binding` ([uploader]="uploader"). I know that they are "angular functionality" same as 'event binding' (change) which I set using `_renderer.listen()`.

Is there a way to set directive and property-binding?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, angular not provide to set directive dynamically from the code